# How to know whether the type of the attribute of a class is custom

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class defined like this:

```
public class Company
{
  public Int32 OrganisationID {get;set;}
  public CompanyStatus OrganisationStatus {get;set;} 
  // note that CompanyStatus is my custom type
}
```

Then I compile the code into `Entity.dll`. When I use the below code, I get  `((System.Reflection.MemberInfo)(properties[1])).Name` as `CompanyStatus`. How can I tell if it is a custom type or not, as I am reading all the properties dynamically?

```
Assembly objAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Entities.dll");

var types1 = objAssembly.GetTypes();

foreach (Type type in types1)
{
    string name = type.Name;
    var properties = type.GetProperties(); // public properties
    foreach (PropertyInfo objprop in properties)
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "custom type" ? do you mean if it's a part of BCL (Base Class Library)

Comment: @Tigran I want to capture other than primitive types . If I have attribute List<CustomTypeA> I want to extract Type i.e. CustomTypeA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [IsPrimitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) property to tell if a property's type is not a primitive type or a string

```
if(objprop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || objprop.PropertyType == typreof(string))
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx):

> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

You may also need to check for *arrays* of primitive types, etc.  To see if the type wraps another type use:

```
if(objprop.PropertyType.HasElementType)
    var t2 = objprop.PropertyType.GetElementType();
```

Comment: Thanks . But how to handle the list if my property is  public List<Office> Offices. and I want to extract Office as (properties[3].PropertyType).FullName gives System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Entities.eOffice, Entities, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Comment: Do you want to know the _actual type_ or just if it is a custom type or not?  That's a different question.

Comment: Yes that right The first problem has been solved Thanks for that. Now I wanted to know its actual type as for the above case ((System.Reflection.MemberInfo)(properties[3].PropertyType)).Name returns "List`1"

Comment: The objprop.PropertyType.HasElementType is returning false for List<Office> . I wanted to extract Type Office.

Comment: Use [Type.GetGenericArguments()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) to get the inner type(s).

Comment: As objprop.PropertyType.GetElementType() is returning null it gives error. Please correct me if i m checking wrongly.